# Custom module of common functions

Tags: python, modules, primes

I got sick and tired of writing certain functions over and over again, so I made a module that has those functions whenever I need them. I don't use it for code I plan on sharing, so I don't need to worry about portability. I do code in Python 2 and Python 3, so I used a bit of hackery to make it compatible with both.

There's nothing I specifically want to ask about this. I've never written a module before, so I have no context to assess this one. I figured it would be good just to have some extra pairs of eyes look it over instead of asking about anything in particular.

```py
import math
import random
import operator
import functools

# Python 2 and 3 compatibility
try:
    # We're in Python 2, redefine range() and input()
    range = xrange
    input = raw_input
except NameError:
    # We're in Python 3, get reduce() from functools
    reduce = functools.reduce

class cache(object):
    """A cache for functions. To use, define function like this:

    @cache
    def foo(bar):
        pass

    """
    # This thing eats docstrings for breakfast
    # I read a way to fix that on the internet, and then immediately forgot
    # One day I'll find it again

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
        self.c = {}

    def __call__(self, *args):
        if args not in self.c:
            self.c[args] = self.f(*args)
        return self.c[args]

@cache
def is_prime(n):
    """Returns True if n is prime, else False"""
    if n < 2: return False
    if not n % 2: return n == 2
    for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(n))+1, 2):
        if not n % i: return False
    return True

def prime_gen(n=2, max=float('inf')):
    """Yields all primes below `max`."""
    # One day I'll get off my ass and write a Sieve of Eratosthenes
    if not n % 2:
        if n == 2:
            yield 2
        n += 1
    while n < max:
        if is_prime(n):
            yield n
        n += 2

@cache
def nth_prime(n):
    """Returns the 1-indexed nth_prime"""
    if n == 1:
        return 2

    n -= 1 # 1-indexing is hard you guys
    a = 1
    while n:
        a += 2
        if is_prime(a):
            n -= 1
    return a

@cache
def factors(n):
    """Returns a set of all factors of n, including 1 and itself"""
    # i got this off the internet and have only a rough idea of how it works
    # but it's fast so lmao who cares
    return set(reduce(list.__add__,([i,n//i]for i in range(1,int(math.sqrt(n))+1)if not n%i)))

def weighted_rng(weights, values):
    """Input: A list of weights and a list of values. Weights are ints, higher =
    more commonly chosen. Each weight is associated with the value that shares
    its index.
       Output: One element from values, chosen at random. A higher weight makes a
    value more likely to be chosen.
    """
    assert(len(weights) == len(values))

    if not weights:
        raise IndexError('No values in lists')

    # If the weight is 0 it can't be chosen anyway  
    while 0 in weights:
        values.pop(weights.index(0))
        weights.remove(0)

    if not weights:
        raise IndexError('No values in lists after stripping zeroes')

    # Convert the list of weights to a list of ranges
    # e.g. [5,5,10,1] -> [5, 10, 20, 21]
    for i in range(1, len(weights)):
        weights[i] += weights[i-1]

    n = random.randint(1, max(weights))

    # Return the value assosiated with the range the random number landed in
    return values[weights.index(min(filter(lambda i: i >= n, weights)))]

def product(l):
    """Returns the product of all elements in the list"""
    return reduce(operator.mul, l, 1)

def input_gen(skip_line=False):
    """Yield each line in stdin. Setting skip_line to True ignores the first line
    from stdin, then yields the rest.
    """
    if skip_line:
        input()
    while True:
        i = input()
        if i:
            yield i
        else:
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ('You aren\'t using this right! Try adding this file to your '
           'PYTHONPATH and putting\n\n  from toolbox import *\n\nat the top of'
           'another python program.')
```

If you're interested (for some reason), I have a github repo for this thing [here](https://github.com/undergroundmonorail/toolbox.py).

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for in your `cache` decorator is [functools.wraps](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps).

Otherwise, very handy!

Comment: Thanks for setting me on the right track, I couldn't get `functools.wraps` working since my decorator is a class instead of a function, but I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17705456/2114129) and used it. It works :)